# How to find all complex solutions for $z^2 - z^{-2} = 4i$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I've tried using the methods we have been shown in lectures but they don't turn out an answer, could someone please help?

Comment: Please format your question using LaTeX, and put the equation in the message, not only in the head. And BTW, welcome :-)

Comment: Try multiplying both sides by $z^2$

Comment: @KaylaMartin Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

We have that for $z\neq 0$

$$z^2-\frac1{z^2}=4i \iff z^4-4iz^2-1=0$$

then use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 0):

$z^2 - z^{-2} = 4i$ is equivalent to $z^4 - 4iz^2 - 1 = 0$ and set $X=z^2$

Answer (score 0):

Alt. hint:   write it as $\;\displaystyle
z^2 - \frac{1}{z^2} \color{red}{-2i} = 4i \color{red}{-2i} \;\iff\; \left(z - \frac{i}{z}\right)^2 = 2i = (1+i)^2\,$.